# What video protocol do backup and side view cameras use in vehicles, specifically a 2022 Toyota Tundra

Tags: toyota, camera, tundra

I want to tap into the video feed of 4 of the 6 cameras in my 2022 Toyota tundra and convert the video into separate streams I can then transmit to an onboard AI security system. They appear to have 4 connections in the harness, and 2 seem to be 12v power, and the other 2 must be Data.

Is there a common video encoding these cameras use that i could tap into each of them, or are these always some proprietary toyota specific format.

Comment: Welcome ot Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!